# Removing time from a Date object?

Tags: java, datetime, date

I want to remove time from `Date` object.

```
DateFormat df;
String date;
df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
d = eventList.get(0).getStartDate(); // I'm getting the date using this method
date = df.format(d); // Converting date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format
```

But when I'm converting this date (which is in `String` format) it is appending time also.

I don't want time at all. What I want is simply "21/03/2012".

Comment: What does `System.out.println(date)` right after the last line say then? It surely is already in the desired format, right? Otherwise you haven't actually posted the complete code. For example, you might be converting it back to `Date` object later which would get the default time.

Comment: Don't you get just 21/03/2012 from `date`?

Comment: @BalusC yeah....it is desired format..but when converting back string to date it appenda default time....which i dont want...

Comment: Why are you converting it back to `Date` then? :) How does that make sense? The `Date` object represents the epoch timestamp in millis and this of course also includes the time. If your sole purpose is to present it to humans, just convert to `String` in desired format like as you already did. You only need to do this at exactly the very moment you're going to present it to humans. Read the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html (particularly also the `toString()` method).

Comment: yes u r ri8.....but i want to pass this date in one method which accepts argument as a date not string...so for this purpose i want to convert it into date...

Comment: Use `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It’s a date without time-of-day.

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12244292/131157

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The quick answer is :

**No, you are not allowed to do that.** Because that is what `Date` use for.

From javadoc of `Date` :

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

**However**, since this class is simply a data object. It dose not care about how we describe it.
When we see a date `2012/01/01 12:05:10.321`, we can say it is `2012/01/01`, this is what you need.
There are many ways to do this.

**Example 1 : by manipulating string**

Input string : 2012/01/20 12:05:10.321

Desired output string : 2012/01/20

Since the yyyy/MM/dd are exactly what we need, we can simply manipulate the string to get the result.

```
String input = "2012/01/20 12:05:10.321";
String output = input.substring(0, 10);  // Output : 2012/01/20
```

**Example 2 : by SimpleDateFormat**

Input string : 2012/01/20 12:05:10.321

Desired output string : 01/20/2012

In this case we want a different format.

```
String input = "2012/01/20 12:05:10.321";
DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = inputFormatter.parse(input);

DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String output = outputFormatter.format(date); // Output : 01/20/2012
```

For usage of `SimpleDateFormat`, check [SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: @Rangi..i want output in date object..not in string....when i will parse **String output** in date object it will append time also...which i dont want......

Comment: As I said, you are not allowed to do that, that's not what `Date` is for. You have to change the way you describe the `Date`, not change `Date` object

Comment: May I read java.text.DateFormat or android.text.format.DateFormat ?

Comment: @hornetbzz : I'm not familiar with android JDK, however I believe android do have their own way to format a date.

Comment: Answers like these, should be removed as the accepted answer.

Comment: @taylorcressy How do you figure?

Comment: Very bad answer. Removing the time fraction by formatting to string?

Answer (score 136):

You can remove the time part from java.util.Date by setting the hour, minute, second and millisecond values to zero.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtil {

    public static Date removeTime(Date date) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not remove the time part, just sets it to zero.

Comment: I also wanted this exact solution. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: but if you want to compare on date, this works by setting every single time the same.

Comment: Does it work whatever the timezone? If we store a Date like this in a timezone, I'm afraid you could get an other date (d+1 or d-1) when you apply this method with an other timezone... I just want to work with calendar dates, like "aaaa-mm-dd", with no time. I'm starting to think that "String" is the most advanced Class to represent a calendar date in Java.

Comment: java.util.Date is timezone independent. Use java.util.Calendar if you want to use timezone specific date/time.

Comment: it's not reliable, used this and results are not consistent. moved to apache comms

Answer (score 44):

Apache Commons **DateUtils** has a **"truncate"** method that I just used to do this and I think it will meet your needs. It's really easy to use:

```
DateUtils.truncate(dateYouWantToTruncate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

**DateUtils** also has a host of other cool utilities like **"isSameDay()"** and the like. Check it out it! It might make things easier for you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be DateUtils.truncate(dateYouWantToTruncate, Calendar.Date); ?

Comment: Calendar.DATE and Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH are marked synonymous in the java doc.

Answer (score 13):

What about this:

```
    Date today = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    today = sdf.parse(sdf.format(today));
```

Comment: Converting a date to a String and then parsing it back again is not a good solution when there is already class available (Calendar) to directly change the components of the date that you want.

Answer (score 9):

What you want is **impossible**.

A `Date` object represents an "absolute" moment in time. You cannot "remove the time part" from it. When you print a `Date` object directly with `System.out.println(date)`, it will always be formatted in a default format that includes the time. There is nothing you can do to change that.

Instead of somehow trying to use class `Date` for something that it was not designed for, you should look for another solution. For example, use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date in whatever format you want.

The Java date and calendar APIs are unfortunately not the most well-designed classes of the standard Java API. There's a library called [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which has a much better and more powerful API.

Joda-Time has a number of special classes to support dates, times, periods, durations, etc. If you want to work with just a date without a time, then Joda-Time's [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class would be what you'd use.

*edit* - note that my answer above is now more than 10 years old. If you are using a current version of Java (Java 8 or newer), then prefer to use the new standard date and time classes in package `java.time`. There are many classes available that represent just a date (day, month, year); a date and time; just a time; etc.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12244292/131157

Answer (score 5):

```
Date dateWithoutTime =
    new Date(myDate.getYear(),myDate.getMonth(),myDate.getDate())
```

This is deprecated, but the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

May be the below code may help people who are looking for zeroHour of the day :

```
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    GregorianCalendar todayDate_G = new GregorianCalendar();
    gcd.setTime(currentDate);
    int _Day    = todayDate_GC.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int _Month  = todayDate_GC.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
    int _Year   = todayDate_GC.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);

    GregorianCalendar newDate = new GregorianCalendar(_Year,_Month,_Day,0,0,0);
    zeroHourDate = newDate.getTime();
    long zeroHourDateTime = newDate.getTimeInMillis();
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I can understand the direction you are pointing in, and the idea is good, but the code is not clear and contains a number of errors. todayDate is not used, nor is todayDate_G (probably misspelt) and todayDate_GC is not defined (probably misspelt). Also gcd is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

you could try something like this:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DtTime {
public static void main(String args[]) {
String s;
Format formatter;
  Date date = new Date();
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  s = formatter.format(date);
  System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

This will give you output as`21/03/2012`

Or you could try this if you want the output as `21 Mar, 2012`

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DtTime {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Date date=new Date();
String df=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
System.out.println(df);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write that for example:

```
private Date TruncarFecha(Date fechaParametro) throws ParseException {
    String fecha="";
    DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    fecha =outputFormatter.format(fechaParametro);
    return outputFormatter.parse(fecha);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is three years old and already has an accepted answer. You should answer more current questions.

Answer (score 2):

The correct class to use for a date without time of day is `LocalDate`. `LocalDate` is a part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

So the best thing you can do is if you can modify the `getStartDate` method you are using to return a `LocalDate`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IE"));

    LocalDate d = eventList.get(0).getStartDate(); // We’re now getting a LocalDate using this method
    String dateString = d.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(dateString);
```

Example output:

> 21/03/2012

If you cannot change the `getStartDate`, you may still be able to add a new method returning the type that we want. However, if you cannot afford to do that just now, convert the old-fashioned `Date` that you get (I assume `java.util.Date`):

```
    d = eventList.get(0).getStartDate(); // I'm getting the old-fashioned Date using this method
    LocalDate dateWithoutTime = d.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
            .toLocalDate();
```

Please insert the time zone that was assumed for the `Date`. You may use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` for the JVM’s time zone setting, only this setting can be changed at any time from other parts of your program or other programs running in the same JVM.

The `java.util.Date` class was what we were all using when this question was asked 6 years ago (no, not all; I was, and we were many). java.time came out a couple of years later and has replaced the old `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateFormat`. Recognizing that they were poorly designed. Furthermore, a `Date` despite its name cannot represent a date. It’s a point in time. What the other answers do is they round down the time to the start of the day (“midnight”) in the JVM’s default time zone. It doesn’t remove the time of day, only sets it, typically to 00:00. Change your default time zone — as I said, even another program running in the same JVM may do that at any time without notice — and everything will break (often).

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Date represents a **date/time** down to milliseconds.  You don't have an option but to include a time with it.  You could try zeroing out the time, but then timezones and daylight savings will come into play--and that can screw things up down the line `(e.g. 21/03/2012 0:00 GMT is 20/03/2012 PDT).`

What you might want is a `java.sql.Date` to represent only the date portion (though internally it still uses ms).

Comment: i tried to zeroing time..but i want only date no time..not even 0:0:00

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a fudge but you could use java.sql.Date. This only stored the date part and zero based time (midnight)

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
c.set(Calendar.DATE, 5);
java.sql.Date d = new java.sql.Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("date is  " + d);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println("formatted date is  " + df.format(d));
```

gives

```
date is  2011-12-05
formatted date is  05/12/2011
```

Or it might be worth creating your own date object which just contains dates and not times. This could wrap java.util.Date and ignore the time parts of it.

Comment: Using java.sql.Date sets the time of day to 00:00:00 (midnight) **for UTC/GMT**. When translated to your own time zone, you'll get a different time-of-day (unless you live in Iceland). So this is not a good solution.

Comment: [Iceland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland)'s time zone is UTC/GMT all year long, without any Daylight Saving Time (DST) nonsense. A handy factoid if you use Mac OS X or other OSes that do not easily let you set your servers to UTC/GMT as a time zone – You can set Reykjavík, Iceland as the time zone to effectively get UTC/GMT.

Answer (score 0):

```
String substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

In other words you know your string will be 10 characers long so you would do:

```
FinalDate = date.substring(0,9);
```

Comment: yeah....but i want date in Date object...so when i will convert this String in Date object it will append time also..but u dont want time...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to work out here is to use java.sql.Date as sql Date doesn't have time associated with it, whereas java.util.Date always have a timestamp.
Whats catching point here is java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date, therefore java.util.Date variable can be a reference to java.sql.Date(without time) and to java.util.Date of course(with timestamp).

Comment: **Incorrect.** A [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) object does indeed have a time-of-day. That time is set to the first moment of the day in UTC, `00:00:00.000`. Clearly stated in the JavaDoc. The `java.sql.Date` class is a hack, created because in its early years Java lacked a date-only type to match the date-only [`DATE` type in SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Date_and_time). If you truly want a date-only without any time-of-day or time zone, use the `LocalDate` class found in (a) Joda-Time or (b) the new java.time bundled in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

In addtition to what  @jseals has already said. I think the org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils class is probably what you should be looking at.

It's method : truncate(Date date,int field) worked very well for me.

JavaDocs : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#truncate(java.util.Date, int)

Since you needed to truncate all the time fields you can use :

```
DateUtils.truncate(new Date(),Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8+, use  **java.time.LocalDate** type instead.

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(now.toString());
```

The output:

```
2019-05-30
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: Does not address the Question. The problem starts with a `Date` object in hand. The Question is not asking for the current date. We already have [a complete Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52738846/642706) using `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following and utilize it.

```
String ex_date = "2023-03-28 21:37:44.0";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd"); 
String strDate2= formatter.format(Timestamp.valueOf(ex_date));
```

Comment: This code does not work in all cases. And even if it did, I very strongly recommend that you do not use `TimeStamp` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52738846/5772882).

Answer (score -1):

You can also manually change the time part of date and format in **"dd/mm/yyyy"** pattern according to your requirement.

```
  public static Date getZeroTimeDate(Date changeDate){

        Date returnDate=new Date(changeDate.getTime()-(24*60*60*1000));
        return returnDate;
    }
```

If the return value is not working then check for the context parameter in web.xml.
eg.

```
   <context-param> 
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: `Date returnDate=new Date((changeDate.getTime()/(24*60*60*1000))*(24*60*60*1000));`
you need to divide the time component and multiply it again. Subtracting time will take it to previous day same time

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to make it hard just follow a simple way

date is a string where your date is saved

```
String s2=date.substring(0,date.length()-11);
```

now print the value of `s2`.
it will reduce your **string length** and you will get only date part.

Comment: Just use Apache Utils DateUtils.truncate(dateYouWantToTruncate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Answer (score -3):

Can't believe no one offered this shitty answer with all the rest of them. It's been deprecated for decades.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
...
    Date hitDate = new Date();
    hitDate.setHours(0);
    hitDate.setMinutes(0);
    hitDate.setSeconds(0);
```

Comment: And deprecated for a reason. Those methods work unreliably across time zones.