# strip time from timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

Why cannot I clear the time from a timestamp this way:

```
one day == 24 * 3600 * 1000 == 86400000 milliseconds.

long ms = new Date().getTime();  //Mon Sep 03 10:06:59 CEST 2012
Date date = new Date(ms - (ms % 86400000));
```

how come this is `Mon Sep 03 02:00:00 CEST 2012` instead of `Mon Sep 03 00:00:00 CEST 2012`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I actually want to compare it to another date not taking into account time of day

To compare dates I suggest using JodaTime which supports this functionality with [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html)

```
LocalDate date1 = new LocalDate(); // just the date without a time or time zone
LocalDate date2 = ....
if (date1.compareTo(date2) <=> 0)
```

Note: this will construct timezone-less LocalDates which is appropriate for the default timezone. As long as you are only talking about the timezone where the default timezone for the machine has been set, this is fine. e.g. say you have a timezone of `CEST` then this is fine for most of Europe.

---

Using the built in time functions you can do something like

```
public static int compareDatesInTimeZone(Date d1, Date d2, TimeZone tz) {
    long t1 = d1.getTime();
    t1 += tz.getOffset(t1);
    long t2 = d2.getTime();
    t2 += tz.getOffset(t2);
    return Double.compare(t1 / 86400000, t2 / 86400000);
}
```

Comment: no, I actually want to compare it to another date not taking into account time of day

Comment: For that you need to consider what your time zone is.

Comment: but what do I need time zone for if I am comparing just dates?

Comment: I suggest you use JodaTime, see my example.

Comment: Your `new LocalDate()` call comment is a bit misleading - because it will use the current time *in the system local time zone*.

Comment: @fatra: You keep asking us which time zone to use, but we can't answer that for you. That depends on your problem domain. Do you understand that the same instant in time will have different dates in different time zones? You need to think about what kind of date you're *really* trying to compare. What are you actually trying to achieve, in concrete terms? Who cares about which date the timestamp falls into, and what time zone do *they* care about?

Answer (score 5):

> Why cannot I clear time from timestamm this way

You're correctly clearing the time part *in UTC*. The millisecond values in `Date` are always relative to January 1st 1970 midnight *in UTC*. However, you're not *displaying* it in UTC, because of the way `Date.toString()` works (it always uses the system local time zone). Note that a `Date` itself has *no concept* of a time zone. It's *just* a number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970 midnight UTC.

The concept of "clearing a time from a timestamp" doesn't really make sense without specifying which time zone you're talking about, as the same timestamp will have different times of day (and even dates) in different time zones.

To be honest, I would suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for any significant date/time work. Then you can create a `LocalDate` which is obviously meant to represent "just a date" - and the translation from a `Date` (or `Instant`) to a `LocalDate` will make it easy for you to specify whichever time zone you want to use.

Comment: so what should I do to compare it to another date not taking into account time of day ?

Comment: @fatra: In what time zone? Do you understand the fundamental problem with what you're asking?

Comment: including a library to do this simple thing is way too heavyweight. I'll just use Calendar.set() method to zero the times

Comment: i don't have any timezones here. I get a date and I have to compare it to another date.

Comment: @fatra I wouldn't describe Calendar as light weight in any sense of the word. ;)

Comment: so I could just use the basic say GMT

Comment: @fatra: "i don't have any timezones here." Then the concept of a date for an instant in time is meaningless.

Comment: @fatra: Well your existing code already gets the date in UTC... you shouldn't just pick an arbitrary time zone; you should work out what your problem actually calls for. We don't have enough context to help you with that at the moment.

Comment: @fatra You have to know which time-zone you are talking about to make a meaningful date comparison. Two dates can be the same day in one Time Zone but different days in another.

Comment: @PeterLawrey so including another library to compare simple dates is more lightweight than using native Java ?

Comment: @fatra Your original code assumed GMT which you say doesn't work for you.

Comment: @fatra For one comparison no. For an application which has multiple ill defined date operations, it will save you more head ache than it costs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
String strDate = df.format(c.getTime()));
```

Now this way you can have the another date, and then compare it....as they are now in String format.