# Get all offers for todays date

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Say I have a Entity representing offers and a CrudRepository exposing the offers. How can get all offers for today? Naturally my Offer entity have a Date attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OfferRepository.java:

```
public interface OfferRepository extends CrudRepository<Offer, Long> {
  List<Offer> findAllByDate(Date date);
};
```

When you want the data:

```
List<Offer> offers = offerRepository.findAllByDate(new Date());
```

Update:

Actually, you can do this too:

```
public interface OfferRepository extends CrudRepository<Offer, Long> {

  @Query("select o from Offer o where date between CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE + 1")
  List<Offer> findAllByDateToday();
};
```

Comment: Probably need to zero out the time on the new Date() for this to work.

Comment: That's exactly what is need! And also the reason for asking the question in the first place. I thought that there perhaps was a better way. Regardless [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10331747/672009) helped.