# How can I Convert timestamp String to Date in Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-date, android-dateutils

I want to convert timestamp to date in android, I tried this code but not get expected result.

My Code Is.

```
String timeStampST = "2016-12-13 09:47:11";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(timeStampST);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Out Put

```
Tue Dec 13 16:15:02 GMT+05:30 2016
```

Expected Out Put

```
Tue Dec 13 2016
```

I need day in my output

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9816867/5013893) to a similar question.

Comment: @apat No, I want day in out put, pls check the expected out put

Answer (score 3):

Kindly copy paste this answer. It will help you.

```
        String timeStampST = "2016-12-13 09:47:11";
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = null;
        String resultDate = null;
        try {
            date = fmt.parse(timeStampST);
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy");
            resultDate = fmtOut.format(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

## OUTPUT

resultDate = 12/13/2016

Comment: How can i get day in that

Comment: He wants the day of the week and the month name, so the format should be "EEE MMM dd yyyy"

Comment: @JihinRaju Please see my updated answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @MicheleDaRos Thank You

Comment: @DharmbirSingh Thank You

Comment: @JihinRaju You're welcome dude. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this method with string and input and output format.

```
  public static String parseDateToddMMyyyy(String time, String inputPattern, String outputPattern) {
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
    Date date;
    String str = null;
    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(time);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: what is inputPattern and outPutPattern

Comment: input pattern for you will be -(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) 2016-12-13 09:47:11, output pattern will be -EEE MMM dd yyyy